# How do I control compiler settings with truffle?

Tags: truffle

I'm using [truffle development environment](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) for prototype contract development and I need to change compiler setting (e.g. turn optimization on and off).

The [documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/) for the development environment does not say how to control the compiler settings.  How do I do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The configurations for the compiler settings [can be found in the advanced section of the documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#solidity-compiler-configuration):

You will need to update your truffle.js configuration file to include the following:

```
module.exports = {
...
    solc: {
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 1500
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: weird, keyword search missed this a week ago.  thanks!

I tested the settings and gasUsed changed, so looks correct.

Comment: ROFL didn't find it a week ago because you just added it.  Thanks!  https://github.com/trufflesuite/trufflesuite.github.io/commit/11e6e6e058b3f73e2e4a9045dd9d359dbae2f13b#diff-c67a290807d69e02561f9334ef81f234

Comment: Is there a way to compile only current directory?

Comment: @JohnMathilda ask that as a standalone question please.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation link in the chosen answer is no longer valid.
Relevant section of the [documentation can now be found here](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration.html#compiler-configuration).

P.S. I can not comment. Had to leave this as an answer.